# Using Analog potentiometer as a digital one to SW control

Tags: microcontroller, adc, potentiometer

I try to read an analog potentiometer that will control specific software functions. 
That means that I want 0 fluctuations in its reading.

For this reason, moving average and other techniques do not work. What I want to do is to use this pot as a digital potentiometer with values from 0 to 63 (6bits) even though I am reading a 8bits value.

What is the best technique to achieve this?

Comment: as for reading 6 bits out of 8, why not just right shift by two? "analogValue >> 2" is the syntax. As for the "0 fluctuations in its reading" if you mean what I infer you do, then moving averages is one of the best ways for you to do that.

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum thanks for your answer but this does not help since it does not solve systematically the issue of code transitions. Example 0x7F (127) - 0x81 (129) would result in 0x1F (31) - 0x20 (32). Filtering also in not enough. As much as you can filter you might also be still very close to a code transition and you will experience fluctuations, unless I am being pessimistic

Comment: @jsotola, thanks. Sure but analog pots are significantly cheaper and I am sure they can do the job.

Comment: Add hyesterisis protection, and that should fix that problem. Though this stops the right shifting from being useful until after hysterisis protection has been dealt with.

Comment: "I want 0 fluctuations in its reading", Above all you need to have an steady supply. stable voltage reference (Arduino is not steady). then try adding an RC filter on the pot output see if that works or not. I had a somehow similar situation and fixed it with an RC filter.

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum yes, hysteresis, but OP only has 2-bits worth to play with. The underlying 8-bit A-to-D had better be good. BTW - a digital pot suggests to me a wire-wound type.

Comment: @ambitiose_sed_ineptum, I just read your answer. That's exactly how I solved the issue. Two bits are enough. That's definitely the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> What I want to do is to use this pot as a digital potentiometer with values from 0 to 63 (6bits) even though I am reading a 8bits value.

That's a tough problem, and it's probably impossible to solve reliably without exploiting the fact that you can, in fact, change the voltage across the potentiometer.

So, first of all, the 8-bit ADC is probably not the thing you'll want to use to determine the value of your resistance.

## Discharge timer approach

Instead, you could implement a much higher-resolution ADC by using a timer/counter to determine the value of the potentiometer:

1. Set an output (p1) pin to high. Use that to charge a capacitor that goes from that pin to ground and is in parallel to your potentiometer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE7hUy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2. the time it takes to discharge the capacitor through the potentiometer depends on the value of R1 – and thus, by measuring that time, you can easily calculate R1! 
   So, after charging the capacitor, reconfigure the output pin to an input pin.
3. count the time it takes for the output to become low. Since your microcontroller certainly runs at several MHz, and you're free to choose C1 however large you want, this will give you a lot of resolution.

Problems here:

1. It's hard to get very accurate capacitors
2. the low/high transition will be temperature-dependent
3. and so will be R1 even if you don't move it at all.

This is a very common approach – in fact, a lot of systems use this approach to measure a capacitance (in touch sensors), where the capacitor is adjustable but the resistor is fixed. It works.

## Dithering for higher resolution

The problem that you have very finite resolution is one very well-understood mathematically. The solution is easy:

1. You add noise of known probability distribution to the phenomenon you want to observe
2. You observe the noisy observation and do statistics on the values
3. you infer the phenomenon you wanted to observe from the statistic.

To illustrate:

- assume you have a voltage \$V_0=4.2\$ V, but your ADC's decision boundaries are 4V and 5V.
- You add some noise \$N\$ to your voltage with mean 0 V and some finite variance.
- You measure the resulting noisy signal \$X=V_0+N\$ a lot of times (\$K\$ times), giving you a sequence of random observations \$X_k,\,k = 1,\ldots K\$.
- The weak law of large numbers says that the average of a large number (\$K\$) of observations \$X_k\$ of a random variable \$X\$ converges to the actual expected value of \$X\$, i.e. \$\frac 1K \sum\limits_{k=1}^K X_k \rightarrow µ_{X_0}\$.

So, in short, you intentionally noise up your observation, but then average the result to cancel out the noise and get an actual estimate for the underlying value.

The problem here is that adding "some" noise and averaging isn't enough in your case, because your observations \$X_k\$ are quantized, and the amount of noise you need to "cross" a step depends on the position of the actual voltage inside your interval.

You'd basically would want to write a probability-maximizing estimator (maximum likelihood, ML estimator) that given some distribution of observed values gives you the likeliest true value.

However, in the case of low-kurtosis symmmetric zero-mean noise, and because you "only" need to gain a few bits in resolution to get a good measurement: Your average of observed values will be pretty close to your actual value, if you just observe a couple hundred values – and that should really be no problem for a microcontroller with an ADC!

So, add noise to the high-side voltage of your potentiometer. That can happen through a random number generator in your microcontroller firmware used to control a DAC, but it really also is reasonable to just flip a pin high and low randomly, and couple that capacitively into your readout.

## Really, get better components

The above are cheap and easy solutions, but honestly: get an optical encoder if you actually want to have an accurate six bit turn knob. Potentiometers really aren't known for their accuracy, so what you'd be measuring would probably really not have enough bits of useful information to begin with, unless it's very expensive – what good is it if you can simulate having a 20 bit ADC, when the actual uncertainty of potentiometer contact and temperature makes for 5% error, easily?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why shifting 2 bits to the right doesn't do exactly what the asker asked for

Comment: because his "switchover" angles do not correspond to that, as far as I gathered, and also, ringing made that worse.

Comment: @ScottSeidman ... or at least that is what I gathered from the question + comments

Comment: @ScottSeidman as I wrote above: take two samples e.g 0x7F (127) and  0x81 (129). RIght shift them : 0x1F (31) and  0x20 (32). You see? This can only work in some cases depending on where you are in the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers. A possible way to solve the problem is with simple thresholds. If the ADC noise floor is below the expected useful resolution (in this base 6bits), then you can simply make sure that next sampled value stays within it. Basically, for every new conversion, you check that the 8bits sample is > (the old one +/- threshold) and if it's the case you consider the new value. The threshold is your noise level in LSB. Basically, Hysteresis.